# HashMap as Value for custom Annotation

Tags: java, spring-boot

I would like to be able to define a hash map as a parameter value for an annotation because I want to use this hash map within the application. The idea is not to maintain the data multiple times. The data is static and only needs to be adjusted when a new key-value pair is added.

Of course, the following definition does not work because HashMap is not allowed as a type in an annotation.

```java
public static final HashMap<String, String> dataX = new HashMap<>() {
    {
        put("A", "X1");
        put("B", "X2");
        put("C", "X3");
    };
};

@Data(data = dataX)
private String property;

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
public @interface Data {
    Map<Integer, String> data() default new HashMap<>();
}
```

The only thing I could think of is to mask the data as JSON.

```js
@Data(data = "{\"A\": \"X1\", \"B\": \"X2\", \"C\": \"X3\"}")
private String property;

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
public @interface Data {
    String data() default "{}";
}
```

Does anyone have an idea how to solve this elegantly?

Comment: If the data is static, then why have it in the annotation at all? Or why not expose the map as static field on a public class? I'm not sure if annotations are the best way to go here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Enums with properties might be a viable workaround:

```
public enum DataMap {
  EMPTY(Map.of()),
  X(Map.of("A", "X1", "B", "X2", "C", "X3"));

  private final Map<String, String> map;
  public DataMap(final Map<String, String> map) { this.map = map; }

  public Map<String, String> getMap() { return map; }
}

@Data(data = DataMap.X)
private String property;

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
public @interface Data {
    DataMap data() default DataMap.EMPTY;
}
```

This has the additional advantage of using immutable maps, so the values can never be changed once created.

---

Alternatively, set a plain enum value and use it to look up your map from another map which is keyed with the enum:

```
public Map<DataMap, Map<String, String>> dataMaps = Map.ofEntries(
    Map.entry(DataMap.EMPTY, Map.of()),
    Map.entry(DataMap.X, Map.of("A", "X1", "B", "X2", "C", "X3"))
);

public enum DataMap {
  EMPTY,
  X;
}

@Data(data = DataMap.X)
private String property;

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
public @interface Data {
    DataMap data() default DataMap.EMPTY;
}
```